# How to add IF condition in dynamic sql function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have a function with the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DIFFC
  (link_query IN VARCHAR2, p_id IN NUMBER, p_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  check_result VARCHAR2(10);
  link VARCHAR2(100); -- Assuming a reasonable length for the link
BEGIN
  -- Execute the link_query to get the link
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || link_query INTO link;

  -- Use the retrieved link in the dynamic SQL
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT COL_ID, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE
      FROM sys.TABLE_COLS@'|| link ||
      ' WHERE (COL_ID = :1 AND COL_NAME = :2 AND COL_VALUE = :3)
      ) THEN ''SUCCESS'' ELSE ''FAILURE'' END FROM DUAL'
    INTO check_result
    USING p_id, p_name, (SELECT COL_VALUE FROM TABLE_COLS WHERE COL_ID = p_id AND COL_NAME = p_name);

  RETURN check_result;
END;
```

I need to change the logic where a count variable needs to be added.
So if the case returns rows >0 then it should return SUCCESS else FAILURE.

I am unsure how to add IF condition in this dynamic statement.

Answer (score 0):

> if the case returns rows >0 then it should return SUCCESS else FAILURE.

A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value, in this case either `'SUCCESS'` or `'FAILURE'` depending on whether `EXISTS` finds any matches; it does not return any "rows" as it always returns one of those two scalar values (the string literals).

The `DUAL` table contains a single row and without a `WHERE` clause (or any other join conditions that may filter it) will always return that single row and will invoke the `CASE` expression for that singular row.

Therefore, you will always get exactly one row of output that will always be either `'SUCCESS'` or `'FAILURE'` depending on whether `EXISTS` matches at least one row or not which will populate the `check_result` variable and get returned from the function.

> I need to change the logic where a count variable needs to be added.

Congratulations, your code already does exactly what you want it to do as there will never be more or less than 1 row generated from the `DUAL` table and `EXISTS` already checks whether the dynamic query returns zero or more rows so you do not need to change anything.

*(Except, to fix the SQL injection vulnerabilities from using dynamic SQL; but that appears to be outside the scope of this question.)*

---

If the problem is with the first dynamic query (and not with the second one with the `CASE` expression) then just catch the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception:

```sql
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    -- Execute the link_query to get the link
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || link_query INTO link;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN 'FAILURE';
  END;

  -- Use the retrieved link in the dynamic SQL
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    '...
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. But i have been asked to modify the code with the count and if conditions. Is it possible or not?